# How to solve the differential equation of the form $\ddot{x}-c_1 \frac{0.2x}{\sqrt{1+0.04x^2}}=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I was trying to get the equations of motion of a cube descending a curved inclined plane described by $0.1x^2$ and I got the folllowing ODE from Newton's 2nd Law:
\begin{align*}
\ddot{x}&=g\sin\alpha\\
\ddot{x}&=g\sin{[\tan^{-1}(0.2x)]}\\\\
\ddot{x}&-g\frac{0.2x}{\sqrt{1+0.04x^2}}=0
\end{align*}
I thought about the linear pendulum ODE ($\ddot{\varphi}+c_1\varphi=0$), which can be solved via Laplace Transform, but this time it wasn't effective...

Comment: I doubt this equation has an explicit solution.

Comment: I actually found the solution for velocity depending on position. Is there any way to find it depending in time from this one?

Comment: A natural first step is to multiply by $\dot{x}$ and integrate; perhaps that's what you've already done?

Comment: If I do so I get the velocity, $\dot{x}$, in terms of $x$, which I've already done.